# AWS ElasticBeanstalk ENV Vars not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm hosting my PHP project on AWS EC2 servers, using Elastic Beanstalk. I've set up my ENV Vars using `php dotenv`, which seem to be getting my vars just fine from my root `.env` file:

**DbConnect.php:**

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = new Dotenv($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$dotenv->load();

$DB_HOST = getenv('DB_HOST');
$DB_USERNAME = getenv('DB_USERNAME');
$DB_PASSWORD = getenv('DB_PASSWORD');
$DB_DATABASE = getenv('DB_DATABASE');

$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_DATABASE);
```

So, in AWS Management Console, I set up the same named ENV vars within software configuration, git pushed, and re eb-deployed. I'm getting a 500 error because the EC2 ENV vars don't seem to be picking up.

[image]

Is there something else I need to do?

---

Update:

`eb printenv` displayed the correct env var values.

Comment: Didn't know who down vote it without any comments. The question looks OK for me with detail. If you downvoted, you'd better to give some reasons

Comment: You can always use `eb printenv` to make sure the env vars are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Have you tried using the `$_SERVER['DB_HOST']` syntax for all the envvars instead of getenv?

Comment: @NickHumrich yes Nick, `eb printenv` printed the correct values

Comment: @NickHumrich any thoughts on why this might be?

Comment: @Growler The environment variables are correct. So perhaps your code isn't retrieving them correctly. Have you tried my second comment?

Comment: @NickHumrich Yes I tried that as well.

Comment: I would recommend trying `$_ENV['DB_HOST']` as well. Though, they should all work the same. You could also validate the envvars are correctly making it to the php container by looking at `phpinfo` result.

Comment: Have you looked at the log to see what the 500 is? SSH into the box and see what your 500 is and update your question.

Comment: @Growler please mark it as tick if that answer yours as well. Thanks

Comment: This is the stupid thing about PHP DotEnv, if it can't find `.env` file to load it complains while as in Ruby version it's not. So just check-in an empty `.env` file into the project source for a quick workaround, perhaps you don't need to change your code at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote from https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

> phpdotenv is made for development environments, and generally should
>   not be used in production. In production, the actual environment
>   variables should be set so that there is no overhead of loading the
>   .env file on each request. This can be achieved via an automated
>   deployment process with tools like Vagrant, chef, or Puppet, or can be
>   set manually with cloud hosts like Pagodabox and Heroku.

You will have php fatal error if you do not have .env file

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException' with message 'Unable to read
>   the environment file at /home/vagrant/Code/project/.env.' in
>   /home/vagrant/Code/project/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Loader.php on
>   line 75

If you would like 
Below is the sample code that you can set `Environment Variable` to check, it only load the **Dotenv** class if it is on local / testing environment

```
if(getenv('APP_ENV') === 'local' || getenv('APP_ENV') === 'testing')
{
    $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
    $dotenv->load();
}
```

Or another method is check the .env file exist or not

```
$filePath = rtrim(__DIR__, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '.env';
if(is_file($filePath) && is_readable($filePath))
{
    $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
    $dotenv->load();
}
```